# How to find axis of revolution of cylindrical objects generated from STL files in matlab?

Tags: matlab, stl

I have 3D models in STL file format. I am reading those files using "stlread" function provided [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22409-stl-file-reader/content/STLRead/stlread.m). It gives me two outputs, faces and vertices. After plotting the vertices (values of x,y,z stored in matrix format) using scatter3 plot, I am getting cluster of points. Is there any way to find out the axis of revolution of those cluster of point?

Currently, I used kmeans clustering algorithm to find out one centroid for all the points. Then drawing normal from each plane(xy,yz,zx) on centroid. After getting 3 normals, I calculated distance between each normal and each point. I stored those values in three vectors one for each normal. The normal which has least unique distances will be axis of revolution. This was working for symmetric rotational objects. But for unsymmetrical objects which has some elongation from the rotational surface, the centroid is shifted thus it is not able to generate proper axis of rotation.

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand the problem correctly, but it sounds like something that might be done with principle component analysis? Can you show a plot of the data and draw the desired axis in?

Comment: The axis of revolution is one of the axes of inertia of the object. As TheodorBecker writes, PCA is the way to obtain the axes of inertia.

Comment: If you want a more detailed answer, posting your data would help. Btw., you don't need k-means to find a single centroid for all data; `mean` will do just fine. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have done it using circle_fit function available online and then used that to find the centre point. The axis will be the normal drawn from that point. K-means works fine for symmetric objects which could be made from single curve rotated around the axis, but for objects like pitcher the centroid is shifted a bit off. PCA is the better option but I don't have better idea about PCA. Thanks for the suggestion that helped a lot.